# Returning string from database as currency

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following query

```
SELECT        SUM(Price) AS Sales
FROM            BarOrder
WHERE        (OrderDate <= @OrderDateEnds) AND  (OrderDate >= @OrderDateStarts)
```

My Price field is set up as Float so that is able to store cents. That part works fine. Now I want to retrieve the information in currency format using the following

```
   lblTodayAmount.Text = Cstr(BarOrderTableAdapter.TodaysSalesAmount(CDate(strEndDay), CDate(strBeginDay)))("C")
```

I get the following:

```
Conversion from string "C" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

if I do the following:

```
BarOrderTableAdapter.TodaysSalesAmount(CDate(strEndDay), CDate(strBeginDay))("C")
```

Then I get:

```
No default member found for type 'Double'.
```

Comment: "My Price field is set up as Float" - fix that first....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ToString`, not `CStr`

```
lblTodayAmount.Text = BarOrderTableAdapter.TodaysSalesAmount(CDate(strEndDay), CDate(strBeginDay)).ToString("C")
```